# Dynamically generating a thumbnail image from an URL image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, url, thumbnails

I was wondering if anyone has some code/useful link explaining on how I could do this.
I would most likely use it this way:

```
<img src="ShowThumb.aspx?image=http://the_image.jpg" alt="" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are several steps involved. Which part are you having problems with?

Comment: [ASP.NET Thumbnail Solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/thumbtools.aspx) what you're looking for?

Comment: I found this: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article63.aspx, I was able to get is working. But how can I modify it so that I don't have to first to save the image as a local file ?

Comment: @Tenza - Please see my answer. It saves it to a memory stream, therefore no need to save it as a local file. If theres something you don't understand, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using an `.aspx` file, use a Generic Handler file (`.ashx`). This means you only require the 1 file (no markup file), so its a bit neater and a bit quicker. Afterall, you're not generating a web form, so an `.aspx` file isn't what you're after.

You can make use of [`System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to produce a thumbnail.

Something as simple as this will work:

```
Bitmap bmpOut = new Bitmap(width, height);
Bitmap B = new Bitmap(context.Server.MapPath(ImageURL));

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
g.DrawImage(B, 0, 0, width, height);


context.Response.ContentType = "image/PNG";
MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream();
B.Save(MemStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

B.Dispose();

MemStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
```

Where `width` & `height` are `integer` values, and `ImageURL` is a local URI string

I wouldn't resize your image using width/height attributes in HTML/CSS. This means you are sending the full size image to the client wasting everyones bandwidth and time! Furthermore, when HTML resizes it, it usually does a shoddy distorted job of it.

---

On a side note, I used to generate on-the-fly thumbnails like this, but decided that the performance was compromised as you are resizing the image everytime a HTTP request is made.

Therefore, whenever the main image was uploaded, I saved the thumbnail to a physical location, and called that in my HTML.

Comment: Is it possible to use something like this, without having to save the image as a local file, but rather get it directly from the source as a stream?

Comment: Yup, thats exactly what this code does. It saves it to a memory stream

Comment: And considering your experience, perhaps using some kind of web service would be better, since I wouldn't be spending space nor processing.

Comment: @Tenza - I'm not sure what benefit a web service would be?

Comment: Personally, I like to use the [GetThumbnailImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx) method on the Image class (which Bitmap inherits from). Much more convenient, although I believe it always uses JPEG encoding and you can't set the quality.

Comment: @Yadyn - Yeah I've had bad experiences with that in the past in terms of quality, so I always stick with DrawImage now, much more freedom.

Comment: @Curt - im sorry, i mean like how they do here on [thumbalizr](http://www.thumbalizr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Youre on the right track: I did something like this once, only used an HTTP-Handler (ashx) for that. In there you can use the Image class to load the .jpg and resize and return it.

**DON'T FORGET** to restict the handler to only resize images on your domain, otherwise it could get quite dangerous (easy DOS-Attacks).